# Bootstrapping in R. By Using Nagelkerke R-Squared

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am new in R. I try to use the boot() function in R, by using the Nagelkerke R-squared as the `statistics` parameter. I know that I need a function that measure Nagelkerke R-squared of original over the resample. However, I have no idea what should I put as the statistical function.

I know that Nagelkerke R-squared can be compute by using deviance and Null.deviance given Logit regression. I write the function to compute Nagelkerke R-squared.

```
  NagR2 <- function(Objects){

  n <- nrow(Objects)
  
  reg <- glm(form,
                    family = binomial("logit"), data = datainput)

  mo <- stepAIC(regression,direction = c("backward"), trace = FALSE)
  
  
  R2cox <-  1- exp((mo$deviance - mo$null.deviance)/n)
  R2nag <-  R2cox/(1-exp((-mo$null.deviance)/n))
  R2nag
  }
```

How should I change my NagR2 function so that I can use it as statistic in the `boot()` function?

Comment: and your question is ... ?

Comment: The function needs whatever you want to resample from (often a data.frame) as the first parameter and a second parameter (usually called `i`) which subsets the first parameter inside the function. `boot` uses this to do the resampling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the function, to take in a input data.frame as first argument, and indices of the data.frame as the second, and other arguments, so changing your existing function a bit:

```
NagR2 <- function(datainput,ind,form){

  n <- nrow(datainput[ind,])
  reg <- glm(form,family = binomial("logit"), data = datainput[ind,])
  mo <- stepAIC(reg,direction = c("backward"), trace = FALSE)
  
  R2cox <-  1- exp((mo$deviance - mo$null.deviance)/n)
  R2nag <-  R2cox/(1-exp((-mo$null.deviance)/n))
  R2nag
  }
```

And applying onto a test dataset:

```
library(MASS)
library(boot)

dat = iris
dat$Species=factor(ifelse(dat$Species=="versicolor","v","o"))

bo = boot(dat,statistic=NagR2,R=100,form = as.formula(Species ~ .))

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = dat, statistic = NagR2, R = 100, form = as.formula(Species ~ 
    .))


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original     bias    std. error
t1* 0.3650395 0.01470299   0.0720022
```